# I have to launched my app on google play but some device supporting

Tags: android-support-library, android-screen-support

I have to launched my app on google play but some device supporting. Error message

> ' App_name stopped working'.java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.readiva.divakar.sqlite/com.readiva.divakar.parikshaquiz.QueHome}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=202; index=-1    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=202; index=-1   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310)  at com.readiva.divakar.parikshaquiz.QueHome.showData(QueHome.java:77)   at com.readiva.divakar.parikshaquiz.QueHome.onCreate(QueHome.java:69)   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)   ... 9 more